Allow defined user role to create webform but not alter form settings
I have searched, but have not found an answer to this question, and am wondering if I am just missing something obvious before I submit a bug report.
Drupal 10.2.6, Webform 6.2.2, and an otherwise plain install (performed on simplyest.me to confirm). Post-installation, I created a Formbuilder role, gave it Webform permissions of "Access the webform overview page", "Create webforms", "Delete own webform", and "Edit own webform", but NOT "Access own webform configuration".
After logging in as a user assigned this Formbuilder role (and no other), I can create a form, and add fields, AND I CAN SUCCSSFULLY ACCESS AND ALTER THE SETTINGS FOR THAT FORM, even though my role does NOT have the "Access own webform configuration" permission.
How can I allow a user to create a webform, add form elements to the webform, but not alter any of the created webform's settings? I have users who I want to allow to explore the "front-end" of webform design, but I do not want them moving webforms into production or implementing handlers (yet). I figured a quick and dirty way to do this would be to have a global webform default that unchecks "Allow users to post submissions from a dedicated URL for all webform". This would force users to have to attach a webform to a node, and if their role doesn't have node edit permissions, all remains good with the world.
Am I missing something painfully obvious, or is this a huge bug? If there is some other non-custom way to accomplish what I am attempting, I am open to suggestions.

This may provide some information: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3070715
